# Action Delegate Throws NullReferenceException On Invoke

Tags: c#, delegates, blazor-server-side

Here I have a Blazor server app, where I call C# method `TransferFileName` from Js function. The `TransferFileName` gets the value in parameter `fileName` as expected, but the problem is that
there is `NullReferenceException` in `DownloadFileNameAction.Invoke(fileName);` line.

This is my code:

```
public static Action<string> DownloadFileNameAction;

[JSInvokable]
public static void TransferFileName(string fileName)
{
    DownloadFileNameAction.Invoke(fileName);
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    DownloadFileNameAction = TransferFileToUserForDownload;
}

public async void TransferFileToUserForDownload(string fileName)
{
   var getFileName = fileName;
   // code omitted
}
```

Comment: By any chance: Ist TransferFileName called before OnInitializedAsync?

Comment: @TheTanic No TransferFileName is not called before OnInitializedAsync.

Comment: "Is not called" or "Should not be called"?